# IE9 / IE10 meteorInstall is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, meteor, angular2-meteor

I am developing an Application with the following technology stack:

Meteor + Angular 2. 
In Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 everything works as it should..

BUT:
i have a big problem with my application in IE9 + IE10.
The Application does exactly nothing if I change the Document Modus to pretend IE Version 9/10.

As an Error I get:

> modules.js - syntax error

and afterwards every meteor package claims:

> meteorInstall is undefined

Im going to try following steps:

- Update Meteor
- Update Angular 2

If no one has a good solution, im going to reimplement every part of the app into a fresh project..  (I dont really want to do this :D)

Comment: And what exactly is the "syntax error"?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code in the browser and inspecting the line in `modules.js` that is causing the syntax error?

Comment: Sorry my line was not finished... :(

                                                                                           
module.exports = function (gm) {                                                                  
 var proto = gm.prototype;                                                                             
 const IDENTIFYING = 1;                                                                                               
 const IDENTIFIED = 2;      

... I deleted the whole package (gm) and now it works as expected !!!